# Get first message on channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

How to get first message on channel? I have really no idea how to do this and i didnt found anything on internet. I need it for getting first mention on channel, so if there is some easier way (than getting first message), you can 
also post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all messages with `fetchMessages()` and then loop over and check for mentions:

```
message.channel.fetchMessages().then(messages => {
    messages.forEach((item, index)=>{
        // do something with 
        // item.mentions
        // documentation: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions
     });
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error while getting mentions: ');
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: from what is in documentation, fetchMessages will get 50 messages, when i left limit blank

Comment: Usage of this method has been changed in discord.js v12: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#fetch (`message.channel.messages.fetch()`)